# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' How can I put image in list in the same order？

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote in `views.py`

```
import os
import cv2
from pathlib import Path

path1 = Path(__file__).parent
path1 /= "../test1"

path2 = Path(__file__).parent
path2 /= "../test2"

index_list =[]
for i in path1.iterdir():
  i = str(i)
  if i.split(".")[-1].lower() in {"jpeg", "jpg", "png"}:
      img = cv2.imread(i)
      print(type(img)) #1
      img = img.tolist()
      print(type(img)) #2
      if img is None:
         print("Couldn't open file %s" % i)
      else:
         index_list.append(img)
         index_list = sorted(set(index_list), key=index_list.index)
```

`test1` & `test2` folders have images.

When I run this codes,

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' error

happens. Traceback says Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "views.py", line 33, in 
>       index_list = sorted(set(index_list), key=index_list.index) .
>   print(type(img)) in #1 shows ,print(type(img)) in #2 shows . img of print(type(img)) in #2 has [[[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255] ・・・]].

I think these value is nest of list causes this error. But I cannot understand how I can fix this data. How can I put images data in list in in the same order?

Comment: You can't hash a list. Convert it to a tuple

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 thank you ur comments.I cannot understand ur comments.Would you show me ur intended codes?

Comment: You can't use the set function on your list (index_list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here: `index_list = sorted(set(index_list), key=index_list.index)`. You cannot use set on a list of lists because lists are not hashable.

Instead, try this: `index_list = sorted(set([tuple([tuple(r) for r in e]) for e in index_list]), key=index_list.index)`

Comment: thx ur answer.I wrote ur codes,but TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' error happens in     index_list = sorted(set([tuple(e) for e in index_list]), key=index_list.index) .Did it happens in ur codes?How can I fix this?

Comment: What does img contain? If it is a list, you may need to convert it to a tuple

Comment: img is <class 'list'>.I think already convert it to a tuple  in ur code,but do I misunderstand?

Comment: Img has lists in it that need to be converted to tuple. That must be the problem...